# php input with 1 decimal number

Tags: php, regex, numbers, preg-replace, decimal

all,
I'm making a shopping cart that only accept input number with 1 decimal place.
The following is piece of code I get from a library (with some modification):

```
$items['qty'] = trim(preg_replace('/([^0-9\.])/i', '', $items['qty']));
```

This will accept any number. but I want to make it as only 1 decimal. how to modify the code?

Thanks

Comment: number_format can do that. http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the decimal places after the first decimal place:

```
$items['qty'] = trim(preg_replace('/[^0-9\.]+|(?<=\.[0-9])[0-9+]+/', '', $items['qty']));
```

[**See it**](http://ideone.com/utS6k)

Comment: Hi @codaddict, your sol solves my prob :) But do you know how to also include "," as well as "." i.e 1.4 and 1,4 both are acceptable? thanks

Comment: @mario: You can add `,` to the character class: `$items['qty'] = trim(preg_replace('/[^0-9.,]+|(?<=[.,][0-9])[0-9+]+/', '', $items['qty']));`

Answer (score 1):

this can be done with round function

```
echo round(153.751, 1);  // 153.8
```

this will help [Rounding numbers with PHP](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-round-numbers/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex like ^(\d+.{0,1}\d*)$

But PHP have a concept, the filter, that does a lot of validations for you, http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php

Answer (score 0):

If i understand well the question, you can use number_format

```
$items['qty'] = number_format(trim(preg_replace('/([^0-9\.])/i', '', $items['qty'])),1,".","");
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

add a line:

```
$items['qty'] = sprintf('%.1f', $items['qty'])
```